# Can an Angel Food Cake recipe be converted to cupcakes?

Tags: conversion, cupcakes

I know "standard" cake recipes can be converted to cupcakes by adjusting bake time... is the same true for angel food cakes as well? Or do other things need to be changed as well? Thanks!

Comment: Given [this recipe](http://allrecipes.com/Recipe/angel-food-cupcakes/detail.aspx) using angel food cake **mix** for cupcakes, I expect adjusting just the time is sufficient - but I don't know if it's optimal.

Answer (score 2):

I've made Angel Food mini cakes before. It was just a matter of adjusting the baking time. Using the standard "clean toothpick" method to ensure they were done worked fine for me.